# How to sort an infinite Flux?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have an infinite `Flux` instance produced by a dedicated `Processor` meaning that each element is emitted via `sink.next` (elements come from reactive Kafka `Receiver` if that matters). 
The issues is that every time I try to do something useful like `sort` on this `Flux` it just gives an empty result. 
This applies to `reduce` as well.

Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**

Here's a more concrete example, it gives an empty `Flux`:

```
Flux.<Integer>create(sink -> {
  sink.next(1);
  sink.next(2);
  sink.next(3);
  sink.next(4);
})
    .sort() // If I remove this everthing works as expected
    .log()
    .subscribe();
```

Talking about my specific case, here's the simplified version of what I have:

```
    FluxProcessor<Message, Message> processor = ReplayProcessor.<Message>createTimeout(Duration.ofDays(1)).serialize();
    FluxSink<Message> sink = processor.sink();
    Flux<Message> pipeline = processor;

    kafka.receive()
        .log()
        .map(ReceiverRecord::value)
        .subscribe(sink::next);

    return pipeline; // Work with the pipeline later on
```

Then if I try to either `.sort` or `.reduce` the `pipeline` it always results in empty `Flux`.

Answer (score 8):

## Never `flux.sort()` your infinite stream

As far as I know, it is impossible to sort infinite ongoing stream of data when the order elements within a stream does not have any math beneath.

The sorting implementation in `Flux` collects all the data into the plain [collection](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.java#L7915):
[image]
 so in a few words, your `Flux<T>` is transforming to `Mono<List<T>>` [underneath](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/MonoCollectList.java#L77)

[image]

As you can see from the image above, there is no [magic behind](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/MonoCollectList.java#L77), which means that the element will be emitted only when the `Flux<T>` has been [completed](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/MonoCollectList.java#L121):

[image]

So in the case of

> I have an infinite Flux instance produced by a dedicated

it will not be able to observe any results at all.

## What should I do then?

Basically, if you have a requirement to sort data, e.g., logs, which has order within a stream and you need to guarantee a global ordering for a several sources based on timestamp, etc, then there is a list of algorithms for solving that so then, you can quickly implement using Reactor API (for instance, `Flux.zip` -> `flatMapIterble`, where your iterable is elements from all of your sources zipped together, which means you need only to sort a few of them, or you can implement another, more sophisticated logic with `Flux.combine`)

Apart from that, if it is fine to observe a partial snapshot of your collection, and still keep the rest of it in memory, then you can use `Flux.scan` like in the following example:

```java
flux.scan(new ArrayList(), (collection, newItemToAdd) -> {

   // use bubble sort since your collection is already sorted,
   // so you will reduce complexity to O(n) instead of having `O(n^2)` or `O(nlogn)`

   return collection;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not posted any code as to what you are trying to do i will give as vague answer as you have given us a vague question.

A Flux will only hold values that it can sort as long as there are values in it that has not yet been emitted.

If you have someone subscribing to your service, as soon as an item is ready to be emitted then it will be sent to the subscriber. Sorting means that there needs to be n > 1 in the Flux, otherwise it is considered sorted.

Example:

Your service has no subscriber, but the kafka queue is emitting values. Since no one is subscribing these values will be accumulated server side in the Flux.

As soon as someone subscribes, data will start flowing, and if you call `sort()` then it will sort all "buffered" items and emit them to the client. If it's an infinite Flux, then the sorting has nothing to sort against because as soon as one item is received from the Kafka queue it is emitted.

As you have not posted any code, i am only theorizing what your problems are.

Vague questions, will get vague answers.

Comment: Sorry if I made it unclear, I added the more concrete examples.

Comment: In your example by using sink, you are creating items as they come, and they get emitted one by one exactly when calling sink. If you change it to `Flux.just(1,2,3,4)` you will see that sort works.

Comment: Everytime you call `sink` the flux will set its state to COMPLETE and emitt that item, that item will go through sort, and cannot be sorted, since it has nothing else to sort against. You can't sort a single item, you need multiple items.

Comment: I see... Then, is it possible to kinda _replay_ the whole `Flux` so that each Subscriber will see each item as it was emitting again?

Comment: Look into the `ReplayProcessor`